# How to install Ubuntu in my Windows 8.1 (pre-installed genuine) computer?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-8

I run Windows 8.1 on my HP Pavilion computer. I have not partitioned my hard-disk yet. I want to install Ubuntu as a secondary OS on my computer. Can anyone help me with step-by-step procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you should install Ubuntu in a VM. this has the advantage that you don't need to shut down your Windows OS to get into Ubuntu. Put another way, you could be running both of them simultaneously.

Providing a step-by-step procedure would be long and boring. But, if you have any familiarity with installing Windows based software then the steps are simple:

1. Download and install VirtualBox
2. Download Ubuntu ISO
3. Create a new virtual machine in VirtualBox
4. Start your new virtual machine and connect it to the downloaded Ubuntu ISO file

Beyond that, the steps are simple as installing Ubuntu is very simple.

If you want detailed steps then this link may help: http://navet.ics.hawaii.edu/~casanova/VirtualBoxUbuntuHowTo.html

One more advantage of this virtual machine approach: you can create as many virtual machines as you want to try out other Linux distros, if you are into that sort of thing.

Finally, I would STRONGLY recommend that you try out Xubuntu. I feel it is FAR, FAR better than the original Ubuntu, but that is just my opinion.

HTH!